# How do I set the first day and weeks for Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm new to this: I'm playing with Bootstrap Datepicker and have got it to work with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#datepickeron').datepicker()
});
```

And then a

```
<div id="dateoickeron"></div>
```

But I can't set first day or weeks like in jQuery UI. Normally I can use `firstDay: 1, weekHeader: "Uge", showWeek: true` like in jQuery UI and show 3 months like numberOfMonths: [3, 1], stepMonths: 3.

How do I do this for the Bootstrap Datepicker?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try adding `weekStart` . Visit [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) for more details about it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#datepickeron').datepicker({
   weekStart: 0 // day of the week start. 0 for Sunday - 6 for Saturday
 });
});
```

Comment: i think `showWeek` option is not available in `bootstrap-datepicker.js`

Comment: +1 very true.. showWeek is not available. also one cannot show three months at a time with this

Comment: how to make it work, if my datepicker apears after clicking icon?

Comment: With the bootstrap date-range picker you need to set the firstDay to 1 in the locale object of the options

Answer (score 3):

Some example. Hope it helps. AS usual goes inside $(document).ready(function(){});

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker('setStartDate', '-15d');
$('#fromDate').datepicker('setEndDate', '1d');
$('#toDate').datepicker('setStartDate', '-15d');
$('#toDate').datepicker('setEndDate', '1d');


    // Initialize the dates
$('#cv-rpt-sdate').datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',"autoclose": true});
$('#cv-rpt-edate').datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',"autoclose": true});
$('#cv-rpt-sdate').datepicker('setEndDate', '1d');
$('#cv-rpt-edate').datepicker('setEndDate', '1d');

$('#dboard-att-date').datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',"autoclose": true});
$('#dboard-att-date').datepicker('setStartDate', '-7d');
$('#dboard-att-date').datepicker('setEndDate', '1d');
```

Answer (score 2):

**No need of jquery or javascript-**

You can set this property in Tag itself.

```
property -   data-date-week-start   
type  -    integer  
default  -    0 
description - day of the week start. 0 for Sunday - 6 for Saturday
```

For Example- I have set to start from Monday, then data-date-week-start="1"

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-week-start="1">
  <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to import
import {BsLocaleService} from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
and
import {defineLocale, enGbLocale} from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';

in constoctor you have to add defineLocale('en-gb', enGbLocale);
in ngOnit you have to add this.localeService.use('en-gb');

its working for BS4 with Angular 7+

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice there's a typo in your 'id' element?  Misspelled "datepickeron" as "dateoickeron."  My apologies in advance for not simply adding this in a comment, but I haven't earned permission to do so yet.

`<div id="dateoickeron"></div>`

...should be:

`<div id="datepickeron"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.component.ts file(it's work for ngx-bootstrap datepicker -4 with angular7)

step 1 
import {BsLocaleService} from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import {defineLocale, enGbLocale} from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';

step 2
 in constructor add defineLocale('en-gb', enGbLocale);
step 3
// in **ngOnit* add this.localeService.use('en-gb');

Comment: Hi Nico Haase ...I updated my answer..please check and let me know if you have any query about this