# Why i cannot set the weekstart to Monday?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker (* Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.9.0 (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker))
I need Monday to be displayed first instead of Sunday.

I've tried this: included bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.min.js file (in which weekstart=1); then wrote the following in my script:

```
<script>
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
            autoclose: true,
            language: "en-GB",
            locale: "en-GB",
            weekStart: 1,
        })
</script>
```

Help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the first day and weeks for Bootstrap Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143526/how-do-i-set-the-first-day-and-weeks-for-bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: this is working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143526/how-do-i-set-the-first-day-and-weeks-for-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: nothing works, seems like i'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 0):

Try , instead of `weekStart: 1` use `firstDay: 1`

Comment: @МамедМамедов from the docs use `startDate` instead of `weekStart`